# Stack Overflow start page for Google Chrome

Tags: app, soapi.js, chrome-extensions, google-chrome

[image: Screenshot]

**About**

Basically, what it does is it aggregates questions from Stack Exchange sites, and shows them on your New Tab window. You can select what sites you want to display, filter questions by tags, change themes, and much more.

Now, when you open a new tab, you always see the most relevant questions for you.

I warn you, this extension is a real timekiller. So, for the love of god, if you appreciate your time, don't install it. Or if you're like me, and you just love Stack Exchange sites, then try it out! Who needs time, anyway :)

**License**

Published on CodePlex under Ms-PL license.

**Download**

[Extension page](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/omcplobmjajgpmpcdnbdiblienjeljan)

Please leave any feedback, bugs, suggestions or anything else you want to share concerning this project.

**Platform**

Google Chrome extension written in HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

**Contact**

"Stack Overflow start page for Google Chrome" is developed by Mihhail Maslakov. Currently, it has only one contributor: Aram Sahradyan

**Code**

Written in JavaScript using SoapiJS. Complete source code can be downloaded from CodePlex.